# How to update IntSlider and InsSlider box to automatically adapt to sample size

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I really hope I will find a solution to my issue. I've struggled to find one but it looks like I'm definitely stuck.

I have the piece of code below that produces an interactive scatterplot of two nutriments.

It is updated according to the pair of nutriments in Dropdown boxes, but also to the product type in another Dropdown box AND more importantly to a subset of nsamples of the population one chooses (if "All" then the entire population is selected).

The problem is that this number of nsample depends on the number of sample for each product type or the total population if "All" is choosen.
I'm struggling to find how I can pass reliably to the IntSlider and its box, the updated max number of sample a product type has when it is selected in the Dropdown.

Many thanks

```
class App:
    
    def __init__(self, df):
        self._df = df
        self._x_dropdown = self._create_indicator_dropdown(all_nutriments, 1, "Nutriment1")
        self._y_dropdown = self._create_indicator_dropdown(all_nutriments, 0, "Nutriment2")        
        self._pnns_dropdown = self._create_indicator_dropdown(all_products, 0, "Product type")
        self._plot_container = widgets.Output()
        if self._pnns_dropdown.value == "All":
            vmax = df.shape[0]
        else:
            vmax = df[df["pnns_groups_2"] == self._pnns_dropdown.value].shape[0]
        self._nsample_slider, self._nsample_slider_box = self._create_sample_slider(200, 100, vmax, 100)

        _app_container = widgets.VBox([
            widgets.HBox([self._x_dropdown, self._y_dropdown]),
            self._plot_container,
            self._nsample_slider_box,
            self._pnns_dropdown], 
            layout=widgets.Layout(align_items='center', flex='3 0 auto'))
        self.container = widgets.VBox([
            widgets.HTML(('<h1>Nutriment indicators for product categories</h1>'), 
                         layout=widgets.Layout(align_items='center', margin='1 0 5em 0')),
            widgets.HBox([_app_container, 
                          widgets.HTML(USAGE, layout=widgets.Layout(margin='0 0 0 2em'))])], 
            layout=widgets.Layout(flex='1 1 auto', margin='0 auto 0 auto', max_width='1024px'))
        self._update_app()
        
    @classmethod
    def from_url(cls, url):
        df = pd.read_csv(url, sep=";")
        return cls(df)
        
    def _create_indicator_dropdown(self, indicators, initial_index, description):
        dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(options=indicators, value=indicators[initial_index], description=description)
        dropdown.observe(self._on_change, names=['value'])
        return dropdown
    
    def _create_sample_slider(self, value, min_sample, max_sample, step):
        sample_slider_label = widgets.Label('Number of samples: ')
        sample_slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=value, min=min_sample, max=max_sample, step=step,
                                          layout=widgets.Layout(width='500px'))
        sample_slider.observe(self._on_change, names=['value'])        
        sample_slider_box = widgets.HBox([sample_slider_label, sample_slider])
        sample_slider_box.observe(self._on_change, names=['value'])
#        sample_slider.observe(self._update_nsample, names=['value'])
        return sample_slider, sample_slider_box

#    def _update_nsample(change):
#        ns = change.new
#        self._nsample_slider.max = ns

    def _create_plot(self, x_indicator, y_indicator, pnns_group, nsample):
        if pnns_group == "All":
            df = self._df
        else:
            df = self._df[self._df['pnns_groups_2'] == pnns_group]
        xs = df[x_indicator]
        ys = df[y_indicator]
        plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [12, 12]
        plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 18})
        fig,ax = plt.subplots()
        colorpalette=["#008a4b", "#7fc241","#feca07","#f58221","#ef3e23"]
        sns.set_palette(sns.color_palette(colorpalette))
        sns.scatterplot(x=xs, y=ys, data=df.sample(nsample), 
                        hue="nutriscore_grade", s=80, hue_order=["a","b","c","d","e"],alpha=0.9)
        ax.set_xlabel(x_indicator.split("_")[0].capitalize() + " content (g) for 100g" if x_indicator != "energy_100g" \
                      else x_indicator.split("_")[0].capitalize() + " (kcal) for 100g")
        ax.set_ylabel(y_indicator.split("_")[0].capitalize() + " content (g) for 100g" if y_indicator != "energy_100g" \
                      else y_indicator.split("_")[0].capitalize() + " (kcal) for 100g")
        
    def _on_change(self, _):
        self._update_app()
        
    def _update_app(self):
        x_indicator = self._x_dropdown.value
        y_indicator = self._y_dropdown.value
        pnns_group = self._pnns_dropdown.value
        self._nsample_slider.observe(self._update_nsample, names=['value'])
        nsample = self._nsample_slider.value
        self._plot_container.clear_output(wait=True)
        with self._plot_container:
            self._create_plot(x_indicator, y_indicator, pnns_group, nsample)
            plt.show()
```

Comment: Happy to help but can you simplify your example, removing the stuff that isn't really necessary? https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I just put the script as it is because it might be that the change I need has to be done in a spot of the class I don't know. To simplify I can say the part below produces the slider I'm referring to:

if self._pnns_dropdown.value == "All":
   vmax = ...
 else:
   vmax = ...
self._nsample_slider, self._nsample_slider_box = self._create_sample_slider(200, 100, vmax, 100)


Now the problem is how vmax (therefore the slider box) can it be automatically updated when I select a subsample in the pnns dropdown that has less individuals ?

Comment: I continued to look for solutions and finally solved the issue !!!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of working on the number of sample, I defined a slider that is the % of total sample size as:

```
self._nsample_slider, self._nsample_slider_box = self._create_sample_slider(10, 1, 100, 1)
```

Then in the _update_app function, this % is taken to get the actual number of samples to plot (I had to use the dataframe once more):

```
def _update_app(self):
    df = self._df
    x_indicator = self._x_dropdown.value
    y_indicator = self._y_dropdown.value
    pnns_group = self._pnns_dropdown.value
    if self._pnns_dropdown.value != "All":
        nsample = int((self._nsample_slider.value / 100) * df[df["pnns_groups_2"] == self._pnns_dropdown.value].shape[0])
    else:
        nsample = int((self._nsample_slider.value / 100) * df.shape[0])
    self._plot_container.clear_output(wait=True)
    with self._plot_container:
        self._create_plot(x_indicator, y_indicator, pnns_group, nsample)
        plt.show()
```